# Cannot read property 'price' of undefined node

Tags: node.js, paypal

I am very new to the node js and I get the following error:
**Cannot read property 'price' of undefined**

I used this package: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-node-SDK

Code works without line

```
amount = req.body.price;
```

But I need to post data

Here is the code:

```
var paypal = require('paypal-rest-sdk');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var amount = 5;

paypal.configure({
    'mode': 'sandbox', //sandbox or live
    'client_id': 'AV-UFzoT7Ccua-ubSQwUGx96qVq46ySVLTHGPyMiK4CA6HP2gHNW61-cvN__sIoyxQD-xX9zZupCNi',
    'client_secret': 'ELAElfR-2pjX5PWJpW3iCW0Yd-WQ_0u2LUk3BDO6v6dcSHgYv1mJG3wg6_gWaR3IwGnVvrZ8pFoRz-'
  });

app.post('/pay',(req,res)=>{
    amount = req.body.price;
    var create_payment_json = {
        "intent": "sale",
        "payer": {
            "payment_method": "paypal"
        },
        "redirect_urls": {
            "return_url": "http://localhost:8000/success",
            "cancel_url": "http://localhost:8000/pay"
        },
        "transactions": [{
            "item_list": {
                "items": [{
                    "name": "item",
                    "sku": "item",
                    "price": amount,
                    "currency": "USD",
                    "quantity": 1
                }]
            },
            "amount": {
                "currency": "USD",
                "total": amount
            },
            "description": "This is the payment description."
        }]
    };
    
    
    paypal.payment.create(create_payment_json, (error, payment)=> {
        if (error) {
            throw error;
        } else   {
            console.log(payment);
            for (let i = 0; i < payment.links.length; i++) {
            
                if (payment.links[i].rel == 'approval_url') {
                    console.log(payment.links[i].href);
                    res.redirect(payment.links[i].href);
    
                }
            }

        }
    });
})
```

Thank you in advance

Also, this is how I post argument price in dart:

```
String _loadHTML() {
    return '''
      <html>
        <body onload="document.f.submit();">
          <form id="f" name="f" method="post" action="http://10.0.2.2:8000/pay">
            <input type="hidden" name="ok" value="$price" />
          </form>
        </body>
      </html>
    ''';
  }
```

Comment: What request are you sending to the server? Does it have a body? Also, you're missing a body-parser for express.

Comment: I was adding a few times bodyParser already but was giving me an error, maybe I had a typo, now it works, thanks

Answer (score 0):

PayPal-node-SDK is deprecated and has no support, use [Checkout-NodeJS-SDK](https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-NodeJS-SDK) for all new integrations

Comment: dude i just applied this one, adding new one will take me ages